# La consulta SQL devuelve 0 datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de hacer un reporte pero no me filtra correctamente, al usa la sentencia **LIKE** incluso con los los caracteres (**"%text%"**) ni la igualdad de `where clienteT='text'` pero en otros casos si funciona.

[image: la primera consulta no devuelve nada]

la primera consulta no devuelve nada pero las 2 siguientes si los hacen.
aqui la DATA

**datos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**ticket**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Los datos son obtenidos desde otro sistema, por ende no se controla las mayusculas ni tildes

Comment: Talvez se debe a que al unir las tablas no hay ninguna coincidencia.

Comment: Revisa que al momento de almacenar clienteT no lo estes grabando con espacios al final, LTRIM,RTRIM, podrian ayudarte.

Comment: Prueba a hacer la consulta con like '%HITLER%'. Si funciona puede ser que la separación entre nombre y apellido no sea un caracter de espacio.

Comment: de esa manera si funciona,`SELECT * FROM ticket t INNER JOIN datos d ON t.idTicket=d.idDatos WHERE d.clienteT LIKE '%ADOLFO%'` pero al juntarlo es el problema, y solo en esa consulta, en las demas funciona normal

Comment: ya hice un `UPDATE`, para ver si fue por eso, pero continua el mismo problema

Comment: puedes poner en detalle las dos tablas ticket y datos?

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que no reconoce el espacio en blanco entre 2 palabras en mayusculas
**ADOLFO HITLER** `" "` por tanto probé reemplazando todo los espacion en blanco por el caracter `%` y me devuelve la respuesta, aun no se si tendra errores, pero por ahora funciona.

```
SELECT * FROM ticket t INNER JOIN datos d ON t.idTicket=d.idDatos WHERE d.clienteT LIKE '%ADOLFO%HITLER%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Has lo siguiente para tu tabla datos:

```
update datos
set nombre=replace(nombre,' ', '')
```

Y listo, si lo haces sobre toda tu tabla corriges el haber digitado espacios de más.